# Threading vs async I/O for multiple network connections

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, networking

I have a C/C++ use case where a pair of connections are needed between the same server-client pair. I need metadata from Connection #2 to parse data from Connection #1. I will have many pairs of such simultaneous connections between the same two endpoints. **There are one server machine and many client machines**. These network connections are consumers. Data is produced by another thread.

My initial thought would be to have one thread per connection, but threads would run out that way pretty fast. Then I wonder if async I/O could help on the networking side, such as with the `asio` library. But I have no experience of async networking.

Several questions:

1. If working with `asio`, how would I coordinate my producer thread with it? Can I safely **mix the threading paradigm with the async world** without debugging hell?
2. Can I use async I/O for networking **on a single thread**, and place all the servers and clients under the same eventloop? **Assume there is only one CPU core for now**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your code running on the client side (single pair of connections) or on the server side (many connections)?  What do you mean by  `threads would run out that way pretty fast`? As long as you are properly closing and terminating your threads, it may not be an issue.

Comment: @selbie I forgot to say there are One server machine and Many client machines on the network. There are code running on both client and server machines. I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: async io generally has better performance vs multitheading under high amount of active connection.     look at how http servers handle their connection

Comment: async io with one thread will only make use of one single cpu core , which is a waste and limitation on modern powerful servers

Comment: @bigdataolddriver Thanks. Before I dive into http server code, I don't know what you mean by "making use of cpu cores" in this case. I thought more cores won't cure I/O bottleneck, am I wrong? Basically my question is should I treat the `asio` networking servers and clients with the eventloop there as a single thread ? Or do you mean I should create more eventloops in different processes to use more cores? I modified my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into `asio`, I decided to fix my own misconception with this answer.

I thought the "asynchrony" of `asio` means threadless non-blocking I/O. But it turns out to be otherwise. You could totally work with `asio::thread` and assign the eventloops `io_context::run()` to threads.

Refer to [the asio tutorial](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.12.2/doc/asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html).